# Set column value NULL when changing field to ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models

I had a `CharField` in my model which i later decided to change to `ForeignKey`. So when i try to migrate, it will not go, because i already have char values assigned to my fields. I know i can delete this field in my model and create a new one, and change it everywhere in my code, or i can manually delete all the values in database. But is there a third option, where if the value in the field isn't related to the appropriate id in the parent model, it gets set to null.

Comment: Look up how to create custom migrations, they allow you to write arbitrary SQL to do more complex transformations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [Data Migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations). I would handle this with two migrations. In the first, add a new ForeignKey field and set up a data migration to handle populating it from the existing CharField. In the second migration, remove the existing CharField.

Comment: Thanks. That's what i've been looking for. I'm just starting with python, so i don't know a lot of the basics yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do:

1. Create a new `models.ForeignKey` field on your model.
2. Populate that column through a data migration or through a python shell.
3. Set the ForeignKey as `null=False`
4. Transition all of your queries from using the old CharField to the new ForeignKey.
5. Drop the old CharField.